# Цикличное повторение ключа в шифре Виженера

Tags: python, python-3.x, шифрование

Решил написать аналог шифра Виженера и поместить все это в функцию. Для начала следует растянуть ключ до длины шифруемого текста, чтобы он повторялся циклично:

> *Человек, посылающий сообщение, записывает ключевое слово («LEMON») циклически до тех пор, пока его длина не будет соответствовать длине
> исходного текста:*
>
> *LEMONLEMONLE (текст - ATTACKATDAWN)*

Соответственно, написал вот это:

```
# key_word = 'LEMON'
# message = 'ATTACKATDAWN'
key_word_large = ''
x = 0
while x < len(message):
    key_word_large += key_word[x % len(key_word)]
    x += 1
```

Как итог получилось довольно громоздко, я думал над тем как это все уместить покомпактнее, например в генератор списка, однако остановился на этом. Собственно вопрос состоит в том, как можно укоротить этот участок кода (без импорта модулей)

Кому надо, вот ссылка - https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Ну к примеру, можно не создавать строку-ключ длиной равной длине сообщения, а вычислять по модулю, какой символ был бы в такой строке на данном месте. Также не обязательно использовать длину ключа именно равную длине сообщения, она должна быть не меньше, так что можно написать что-то вроде `key_cycle = key * (len(message) // len(key) + 1)`

Comment: кстати да, спасибо, не думал об этом

Comment: Еще, если скорость критична, все строки лучше переделать в списки символов с помощью `list(str)`

Comment: а какова скорость выполнения этого куска, чтобы считаться неприемлемой ?

Comment: дело не в скорости, просто хочу написать более лаконичный код

Comment: Как определить громоздкость кода?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял, что делать если `message` по длине окажется меньше, чем `key_word`, поэтому код работает из следующего предположения:

Если, например, `key_word = "LEMON"`, а `message = "LOL"`, то `key_word_large = "LEM"`

Сам код:

```
key_word = 'LEMON'
message = 'ATTACKATDAWN'

p = len(message) // len(key_word)
q = len(message) % len(key_word)

key_word_large = key_word * p + key_word[:q]
```

Результат:
`LEMONLEMONLE`